# SKLabelNode upside down possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I'm developing a game in xcode 6 with swift. I have a scorelabel `var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode!`. Now in one of my methods I show my label:

```
scoreLabel = SKlabelNode(fontNamed: "TrebuchetMS-Bold")
scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
scoreLabel.fontSize = 30
scoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor .redColor()
scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x:780, y:180)
addChild(scoreLabel)
```

That shows my score as for example: 2500.
Is it possible to show this upside down?

- 2
- 5
- 0
- 0

Sorry, I wrote this as list, because I wasn't able to write upside down here.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: How do you mean upside down? Can you show an image. The text you wrote as a list is not upside down. Also, can you not just rotate the SKNode? i.e. `label.zRotation = M_PI`

Comment: Yes, I could't write at stackoverflow upside down. I don't mean as a list. `M_PI` I got `Double` is not convertible to `CGFloat`

Comment: `CGFloat(M_PI)` then. Cast it to CGFloat

Comment: Aah thanks but thats not what I mean. I want to show every Number at one line. i.e. 1 under it 0 and under zero 5. Than is my score 105.

Comment: Turn the score into a string and loop through each character. Make an sklabelnode for each character and set it's position. Will make an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom class to loop through each `character` in the `string` and create a separate `SKLabelNode` for each `character`.

```
class SKVerticalLabelNode : SKNode
{
    var fontName : String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.updateLabelProperties()
        }
    }

    var fontSize : CGFloat = 10.0 {
        didSet {
            self.updateLabelProperties()
        }
    }

    var fontColor : UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
        didSet {
            self.updateLabelProperties()
        }
    }

    var text : String = "" {
        didSet {
           self.updateLabelProperties()
        }
    }

    func updateLabelProperties () {
        self.removeAllChildren()
        let length = countElements(text)
        var yPosition : CGFloat = 0
        for character in reverse(text) {
            let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: self.fontName)
            label.fontColor = self.fontColor
            label.fontSize = self.fontSize
            label.text = String(character)
            label.position = CGPointMake(0, yPosition)
            yPosition += label.frame.size.height
            addChild(label)
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used like this

```
let scoreLabel = SKVerticalLabelNode()
scoreLabel.fontName = "TrebuchetMS-Bold"
scoreLabel.text = "2500"
scoreLabel.fontSize = 30
scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.redColor()
scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x:180, y:180)
addChild(scoreLabel)
```

Comment: you can just use `for char in string {}` with a separate counter, to remove the need for all the substring and string.index operations

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SKLabelNodePlus` label for this. 
Here is the link: https://github.com/MKargin0/SKLabelNodePlus

Then, just invert the label by writing `myLabel.xScale = -1`. Its as simple as that!

Comment: Looks like xScale has been added to the standard SKLabelNode now.